# Distinguishing const char * and char * with C _Generic macro

Tags: c, generics, c-strings

I want a function to behave differently when parameter is a `const char *` (like "text") or `char *` (dynamically allocated string).

Is there a way to achieve this using _Generic macro in C?

I tried following code but it didn't run const function.

Edit: Added example

```
#define foo(val) _Generic((val), \
    char *: foo_string,\ 
    const char*: foo_const_string\
    )((val))

char * text = "abc";
foo(text);  //both calls foo_string(val)
foo("abc");
```

Comment: best to post calling code that "didn't run const function" as it "works" for me.  Note `"text"` is an "array 5 of char", not a `const`.  Try `const char *s = "text";
 foo(s);`

Comment: I see, is there a way to handle general "array N of char" for any N? @chux

Comment: Try `(val)` --> `((val) + 0)` to compel conversion to pointer type.  Maybee even `(val)` --> `(+(val))`.  Still hoping for a [mcve].

Comment: According to this [link](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/generic) in the note section, string literals such as "abc" are interpreted as "char*" not "char[4]".

Comment: Q: Are you sure you're using a C11 compiler, in C11 mode?

Comment: yes I am using C11 compiler in C11 mode @paulsm4

Comment: @Strongwill -- string literals are used to initialize arrays of `char` in static memory, and they have type `char[]`, not type `char *`. In most expressions a string literal will _decay_ to a `char *`, but not, e.g., in `sizeof "some string literal"`. [See the Standard description of string literals](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.4.5).

Comment: Oh thanks that sort of answers the question if you look at my previous comment(char[] is interpreted as char*).

Answer (score 1):

The "const" version will run only when you pass it truly const string pointer, so you either have to store it in a const pointer variable or cast your literals to "const char*" manually. Thanks @David Bowling.

> tested with gcc.exe (i686-posix-dwarf-rev0, Built by MinGW-W64 project) 8.1.0

## include

```
void put_const_msg( const char* msg )
{
  printf("CONST MSG: %s\n", msg);
}

void put_non_const_msg( char* msg )
{
  printf("NON CONST MSG: %s\n", msg);
}

#define put_msg(msg) _Generic((msg), \
    const char*: put_const_msg, \
    char*:  put_non_const_msg \
                              )((msg))

int main ( int argc, char** argv )
{
  const char* cm = "Hello there!";
  char* ncm = "How are you?";

  put_msg(cm);
  put_msg(ncm);
  put_msg("KETCHUP IS A GENERIC SAUCE!");
  put_msg((char*)"MUSTARD IS LESS GENERIC!");
  put_msg((const char*)"Well this is ackward!");

  return 0;
}
```

**Output**

```
CONST MSG: Hello there!
NON CONST MSG: How are you?
NON CONST MSG: KETCHUP IS A GENERIC SAUCE!
NON CONST MSG: MUSTARD IS LESS GENERIC!
CONST MSG: Well this is ackward!
```